# ValueError: arrays must all be same length in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, valueerror

I was following [Sentdex's second tutorial on pandas basics](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0UA49Ds1XXo), and ran into this problem. Here's my code up to this point:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import style
style.use('ggplot')

web_stats = {'Day' : [1,2,3,4,5,6],
             'Visitors' : [43,53,34,45,64,34],
             'Bounce_Rate' : [65,72,62,64,66]}

df = pd.DataFrame(web_stats)

print(df)
```

I was really confused when this error message popped up. Please note that I'm on a mac.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Terry/Documents/df.py", line 10, in <module>
    df = pd.DataFrame(web_stats)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 275, in __init__
    mgr = self._init_dict(data, index, columns, dtype=dtype)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 411, in _init_dict
    return _arrays_to_mgr(arrays, data_names, index, columns, dtype=dtype)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 5496, in _arrays_to_mgr
    index = extract_index(arrays)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 5544, in extract_index
    raise ValueError('arrays must all be same length')
ValueError: arrays must all be same length
>>>
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Bounce_Rate has only 5 values, you have to pass arrays of same length to be able to create a dataframe

Comment: Not sure but `Bounce_Rate` has only five values and the others have six.

Comment: Please consider marking answer as correct if it helped. Welcome to SO!

Answer (score 1):

Bounce_Rate has less values than the amount of days / visitors. Check your web_stats dictionary

I.e. adding an item (an `int` i.e. a number) to that list would fix it. But make sure, you notice in the below example I change the list values to [65, 72, 62, 64, 54, 66] according to comments. You will probably want to check which values should go there.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import style
style.use('ggplot')

web_stats = {'Day' : [1,2,3,4,5,6],
             'Visitors' : [43,53,34,45,64,34],
             'Bounce_Rate' : [65, 72, 62, 64, 54, 66]}  # Copied values from tutorial according to comments.

df = pd.DataFrame(web_stats)

print(df)
```

Comment: The actual list is `[65, 72, 62, 64, 54, 66]` in the video tutorial.

Comment: correct, in pandas a dataframe's columns must all have the same length. You could insert a value (if that is what you need, maybe just a typo or something), or it you literally dont have a value for that specific 'Bounce Rate' item, put a NaN there

Comment: Updated answer to use: 65, 72, 62, 64, 54, 66

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs when the length of dictionary values is not the same, you can check the keys and the length of its corresponding values using for loop

`for key, value in web_stats.items(): print(key, len(value), sep=" | ")`

the output will be :

Day | 6
Visitors | 6
Bounce_Rate | 5

now you know that Bounce_Rate is less in length than other keys